# $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} e^{-1/x^2} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am trying the following, not sure if it makes sense.

For every $1 > \epsilon > 0$, $x < \frac{1}{\sqrt{\log\left (1/ \epsilon \right )}}$ $\implies $ $| e^{-1 / x^2}|  < \epsilon$.

That's how we do it for sequences. I am kind of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

When evaluating limits, as long as you know some limits are true, you don't need $\epsilon$. Let $y=\frac{1}{x^2}$. Then $x\to 0\Leftrightarrow y\to \infty\Rightarrow \lim\limits_{x\to 0}e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}=\lim\limits_{y\to\infty}e^{-y}=0$.